# How do I reset an ASP.NET dropdown, on the click of a link, using Javascript? No JS Frameworks

Tags: asp.net, javascript, drop-down-menu, reset

How do I reset an ASP.NET dropdown, on the click of a link, using Javascript? No JS Frameworks.

Edit: reset, as in set the selected value to the first one in the list, as it would be when the page first loads.

Comment: What do you mean by reset?  Does that meaning selecting the top value on the drop down list?  Does it mean clearing out the list and repopulating it with other information?  If you want your question answered correctly you need to provide as much information as possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "reset"? Do you mean change the selected index? Or change the items in the list? Or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this [link](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1161649&page=5)

Do you want to remove all items of the dropdown or Select the first option(Default selected option)?

Try this :

```
document.getElementById("<%#mydropdownlist.ClientID%>").value = 0;
```

or

```
document.getElementById("<%#mydropdownlist.ClientID%>").selectedIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You would probably want to get the control by ID then set the selectedIndex to 0.
for example:

```
var q = document.getElementById('dropdownId');
q.selectedIndex = 0;
```

Hope this helps